# Can you prove p → p using only Deduction theorem?

Tags: logic

I've been asked to prove $\vdash p\rightarrow p$ using the Deduction theorem. We're usually given a list of axioms ([page 20](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~henson/Math570/Fall2009/Math570notes.pdf) of the book, 24 of the pdf) to use in our proofs but not this time.

Can you actually prove this tautology using the Deduction theorem and not repeating the proof in that same page? Since everything on the RHS has to be an axiom, I can't find find a different way of doing it, let alone using DT.

Thank you

Edit:
$p \vdash p \implies \vdash p \rightarrow p$ answered in the comments

Comment: How about Lemma 2.2.7 (Deduction Lemma)?

Comment: Or what do you refer to with "Deduction theorem"?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to that Lemma

Comment: Then: obviously $p \vdash p$. Thus, by the lemma, $\vdash p \to p$.

Comment: You could say...no, deduction theorem requires $p \to p$ as an assumption.  it is the reason $p \to p$ was in the original list of hilbert axioms.